# convert a tuple into a string in python

Tags: python, tuples

i have a tuple

```
tup = ('\x00\x05(^\x9a\xdd\x1c\xb3\xe0T\x00!(\xa8z\xd8', 0, 'ABC', 0, None, None, None, None, None, None, None)
```

i want to convert it in a pipe separated string

```
\x00\x05(^\x9a\xdd\x1c\xb3\xe0T\x00!(\xa8z\xd8|0|ABC|0|None|None|None|None|None|None
```

I'm doing something like this and getting following errors

```
''.join(tup)
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in ?
TypeError: sequence item 1: expected string, int found
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to convert each element to a string first. You can do this with [`map`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map) and [`str`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#str):

```
print '|'.join(map(str, tup))
```

Comment: I was going to say `'|'.join(str(a) for a in tup)`, but `map` is far simpler (and more elegant).